# Font.Color in VBA is slowing down Excel

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I coded a function in VBA for Excel to assign a letter and color code to the font of the cell, depending of 2 differents values.

Basically, the function has 2 parameters for the compared values and the cell that will contains the letter and color.  I use the webdings font, so the letter will look like a symbol.

I know this could be done with conditionnal format but this function will be call in my workbook lots of time, insides multiples sheets, I found out it would be easier to maintain over time with a VBA function and put everything at the same place.

PROBLEM : The use of "currentCell.Font.Color" is slowing down Excel terrably. Even if I initialized the constant color when the workbook open, used some optimization tricks I found on the web, etc.

Do you know why the change of font color is slowing down Excel so much ?

Regards,

```
Const DefUnderBudget = 0.95
Const DefOverBudget = 1.05
Const FavMoyen = 0.98
Const DefMoyen = 1.02
Const FavOverBudget = 1.05
Const FavUnderBudget = 0.95


Const SMALL = "="
Const BIG = "n"


Global RED As Long
Global BLUE As Long
Global YELLOW As Long




Sub InitColors()
    RED = RGB(218, 150, 148)
    BLUE = RGB(149, 179, 215)
    YELLOW = RGB(243, 202, 38)
End Sub



Function setPerformanceIndicator(actualVal As Double, compVal As Double, currentCell As Range) As String


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False



        If actualVal < compVal * DefUnderBudget Then

           currentCell.Font.Color = RED
           setPerformanceIndicator = BIG

        ElseIf actualVal < compVal * FavMoyen Then

           currentCell.Font.Color = YELLOW
           setPerformanceIndicator = SMALL

        ElseIf actualVal > compVal * FavOverBudget Then

           currentCell.Font.Color = BLUE
           setPerformanceIndicator = BIG

        Else
           setPerformanceIndicator = vbNullString
        End If



Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True




End Function
```

Comment: How often are you calling this and how? Each time this function executes you refresh the screen as well as calculate all cells, so if you have a lot of times this gets executed (perhaps in a loop?) you are going to really slow Excel down a lot.

Comment: The function is called from a cell with this instruction "=setPerformanceIndicator(BB10;BF10;BC10)".   And called about 200 times. Not in a loop.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I don't think the issue is Font.Color but the fact that every time the workbook recalculates it recalls this function for every reference to it. My assumption is in a cell you have =setPerformanceIndicator(A1, B1, C1). User function do not get compiled so that can add to the slow down.

Comment: I pretty sure it's the font.color, I commented out the lines with the color change, so the function was simply returning a letter. It was fast, I put back the font color change, the slow execution went back.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Windows is probably having to refresh the screen multiple times.

Before multiple calls, run

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Afterwards,  run

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```